# Will I need a heatsink for this voltage regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator

I am making a USB battery backup with an old laptop battery and a solar panel. I know most regulators have heatsinks, but will my 5v regulator need one? And if I do, how hot will it get?

Comment: What are you going to sync it to?

Comment: I's impossible to say without knowing what current draw you want and what voltage the regulator will be dropping.

Comment: Aside, punctuation would drastically improve the readability of your question. If English isn't your native language (it certainly isn't mine), don't worry about small errors; it's better to have a "." too many than having too few.

Comment: I'm using it to charge phones and I'm not a electrical geek I only know the basics

Comment: See my answer for more details, but in general, you'll probably need a heatsink for non-trivial loads (they're cheap). LDO regulators are not known for their efficiency, but rather their ability to hold a specific voltage with less noise than their switching counterparts. Where sola panels are concerned, you typically want high efficiency. Moreover, the panel will not always be greater than the battery voltage, particularly when it is asked to drive a load. For these reasons, solar converters usually use switching buck/boost circuits with a special controller for battery charging applications.

Comment: You can't just use "I only know the basics" as an excuse. You are here to learn, not to have someon do your job for you. People provided you with additional things to look into, so go look into them. You can't go somewhere, ask "How do I make a car" and then go "uhm I only know the basics so go easy on me" as soon as someone tells you to get a screwdriver

Comment: Hey buddy I'm only 13 how do u expect me to learn all of this when will it ever be helpful I'm just looking for. A solution I already looked at the links and it is way to complicated for me

Comment: Shouldn't be there some age restriction here? Or, at least, a mandatory "age tag", so we can exercise more weighted judgement on question quality and level?

Comment: Age isn't a large factor in this - it's experience. The only real thing that age does is set a maximum amount of experience - as a 13 year old, you can only have a few years of experience. You have to start somewhere. "when will it ever be helpful" - in, well, everything. I've used electronics in similar situations when I was younger in school. Also, if you have another project, things you learn now can be used for those. @AliChen - tags like that [are generally disliked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59077/should-we-be-adding-tags-like-beginner-to-questions/59078#59078).

Comment: @lights0123, there is a reason why education, especially in mathematics and physics, is taught to children in certain step-wise progression. You can't have "experience" in algebra or calculus at age 13, so most engineering advices will go above the head.

Comment: @AliChen yes. However, as a 13 year old myself, I have to say that you just have to deal with what you know and try to learn as much as you can. Sure, I can't design anything involving anything above a couple of MHz, and I've done things like put signal wires under an antenna on my PCBs (whoops!), but I have taken my education of Algebra 1 and used it to learn much more than it. Actively trying to learn electronics starting when I was 10 has given me enough knowledge to understand many concepts, which certainly doesn't go above my head.

Comment: @lights0123, okay, okay, I just calculated that I learned the Ohms Law and beta-gain of BJTs at about 13 as well. After about 55 years since then, I do know what the difference is between now and then. Good luck to you...

Answer (score 2):

I watched your video.  Parker, can I tell you that the regulator's heat sink is the least of your problems.  I'm not trying to sass you, but having read through your question and subsequent comments, I'd advise you against this project.

Some of the people on this site are hopeless amateurs like me, but some are professional electrical engineers.  I'm sure that there will be a general consensus that lithium ion batteries are dangerous.  They can be very dangerous.  They are very absolutely not like normal batteries. The reason your laptop hasn't caught fire is that there are at least three levels of independent protection to stop it bursting into flame.  And it's been professionally designed by many geeks.  I'm not kidding you.

Ripping open the laptop cell carrier with a large blunt instrument risks perforating the cell wall.  There may be current protection in the cell carrier that you'll be chucking away.  And lithium batteries have to be carefully charged with a specialist circuit.  You'll be missing all these protections.  And running anything off a solar panel is tricky as the generated voltage and current can be all over the place.

If your skill level only covers the basics, a dual solar /usb lithium ion power pack using old recovered laptop batteries is going to be way too complicated for you.  Sorry.  Can I suggest that you watch my video, and google "*Are laptop batteries dangerous*".

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pizFsY0yjss

You have been warned :-)

If you continue, just get one 3" square and that should keep the heat down.  And don't use a normal fire extinguisher, it might not work.  You'll need a specialist class D type appropriate for metal fires.

Comment: I will second the notion that there is a skills mismatch

Answer (score 0):

This question is lacking in some specifics, i.e. how many watts is your panel, and what type of battery are you using. Apart from the missing information, it sounds like you may not fully appreciate the complexities of using solar panels to drive a load. To the heart of your question about heat sinking, the basic thermal equations for LDO's are as follows:
The power balance equation for the circuit below is \$P_{in}=P_{out}+P_{LDO}\$. 
[image]

The power dissipated in the LDO is given by 
\$P_D=(V_{in}-V_{out})*I_{Load}+V_{in}*I_{GND}\$ - note that you should plug-in worst case quantities. Basically, it is a function of input voltage, output voltage, and the current.

Once you have a maximum dissipated power for you device, you may calculate the allowable temperature rise for the device using an average ambient temperature. For more details on this step, please see Microchip's AN761, which can be found [here](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00761b.pdf).

Comment: Here is the video the stuff is in the description. So what will the awnser be.  https://youtu.be/1IzWSbJ5Ff8

Comment: I'm not here to do the math for you, I've provided you with the resources you need to make the correct heat sinking choice. Having said that, you can't really just hook an LDO to a solar panel and expect it to charge your battery. Also, you haven't even said what voltage your battery is, what panel you're using, or what LDO you're using. Electrical engineering is not easy! If you want to be lazy, get the biggest heat sink that will fit on your regulator, and have a fan blowing on it.

Comment: There is a short answer to the video you linked to. It's crap; and would cause you to overcharge the Li-Ion battery cell if you used a 7805 regulator. The nut doing the video gets away with not having a heatsink on the 7805 because it will go into thermal shutdown... so the 7805 won't be damaged but the battery almost certainly will in full Sun conditions.

Comment: @JackCreasey, I wouldn't be so quick. The video shows some dedicated charger board, I would say "BMS", which apparently allows to charge a Li-ion battery, and boost up its voltage to 5V USB. The 7805 is used to regulate the solar output to 5V as required by the BMS https://www.aliexpress.com/item/5V-1A-Power-Bank-Charger-Board-Charging-Circuit-PCB-Board-Power-Supply-Step-Up-Boost-Module/32712060303.html The 7805 doesn't overheat since the solar panel in the video is just 6V 100mA, so max dissipation on 7805 is 100 mW. Obviously this a childish design, but what the heck...

Comment: @AliChen No it does not! and it certainly isn't a BMS. .....the Solar panel simply has a 7805 on the back of it. ......the 'charger' you see is a DC-DC convertor to take a Li-Ion 4.3 V fully charged to 5 V USB.  You can see in the video that you either have the solar panel connected OR the Boost convertor.

Comment: @JackCreasey, do you have the datasheet for KFC7113, so you speak so confidently? To my view, the KFC7113 looks like a stolen variant of TI BQ241xx IC. Also, Li-ion can't be charged to 5V, the cell will "rapidly decompose". The project is pretty legit: solar feeds 5V regulator, 5V feeds Li-ion charger, which has a boost function from 4.2-3.6V cell to 5V USB.

Comment: @AliChen ...I speak from the confidence of the video ....where he plugs in EITHER the solar panel with it's 7805 gued to it ...OR plugs in the Boost convertor. So the confidence is that he absolutely is not using the board to provide BMS ...since it's not connected when solar charging. The Solar panel at no time feeds the Boost board, so it cannot be providing the capability you claim.

Comment: No @JackCreasey, you didn't pay enough attention to the video. Author of the video made a solar 5V source, with uB plug. But since this solar source would take weeks (about 100 sunny hours) to charge the 4P 18650 battery, he used an external AC-DC charger (with TypeA to uB cable) to bring the battery into reasonable charge level. Please check the video again.

Comment: Guys. There's an huge assumption here.  The OP probably can't differentiate between a DC-DC converter, BMS or toy train (no disrespect).  And the solar panel could be a huge one off his roof.  And what battery is being used?  As RYS points out, this is not really appropriate for a noob. I would be asking a lot more questions here before building this myself.

Comment: @PaulUszak, all details for this project are explicitly listed in the text caption to this video, with links. No assumptions here, except about exact functionality of KFC7113 IC.

Comment: @AliChen since when do we allow question details to be posted in external videos?

Comment: RYS, I agree, it would be nice if the kid could present an analysis of building blocks and overall interconnect in this project, with full voltage-current-capacity parameters. But since the video was brought into attention, why not to bring facts and skip on assumptions in the discussion? As least the kid asked the right question, give him some credit.